# What did Moshe Dayan say about fighting Arabs?

Tags: israel

I am looking for the details of a quote that goes something along the lines of "It is easy to look like a great general when you fight Arabs" by Moshe Dayan (or maybe Golda Meier).  I believe the context was in reply to some comment about how he was such a great general.

- Who said it?
- When & where was it said?
- What is the exact quote?
- Where is the original source/citation?

I did a few Google searches but couldn't find the quote. Even if apocryphal, would appreciate the scoop on how it came to be.

Note: Although the quote may seem to indicate an anti-Arab sentiment, it is a quote; it represents the speaker's opinion, not the original poster's.

Comment: Why did someone negative one this? It's a serious question (albeit a minor one). At least more historical than the 1969 Life Magazine pretty girl question.

Comment: This website has a bad history of new users (in particular unregistered ones) trying to promote racist content by pretending to ask a question about it. You are a new user, the supposed quote is definitely racist, and this is a question asking about it, so it fits the profile.

Comment: It may take someone who can read Hebrew to find the original quote. Several unattributed versions are out there: "it’s easy to look good when you fight Arabs", "If you have to fight a war it helps to fight Arabs", "easy to look like great warriors when you fight Arabs", etc.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  (extra characters)

Comment: So we have a quote with no exact wording, no secondary source, no associated person and no context. Hmmmmm

Comment: But we do have approximate wording and suspected person.  No clue on source.  Edited in the suspected context.  (Obviously if I knew it all, there would be no question.)

Comment: I know the "repel all suspicious foreign organisms" crowd (common on any web forum and for understandable reasons, e.g. see the Flame Warrior cartoon called "Xenophobe",), think that I made the question as a provocation.  But I am just generally curious to know if the story is true (and what the details are) or a tall tale.  I heard it in the US military, during the first Gulf War.  FWIW, further Googling using Aaron's suggestions led me to this (serious) academic article that discusses the topic, but does not help with the quote:  https://www.meforum.org/441/why-arabs-lose-wars

Comment: Ugg...you put it on hold.  I'm not anti-Arab.  Have read Seven Pillars of Wisdom, taken a class on Islamic history, and have read several popular sympathetic books like Wind in the Sahara and Doomed Oasis.

Comment: Thanks, man.  Not really sure how.  Will you edit it?  I give you full permission.

Comment: I didn't VtC, but this might have gone over better if you already had some reputation on the site. The question looks fine to me now.

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting this site](https://library.osu.edu/projects/hebrew-lexicon/hbe/hbe00610.php) that supposedly quotes the book:

> סיפורו של משה דיין
>   משרד הביטחון – ההוצאה לאור, 1997
>   [ספר נידח שגם אזל כי שארית עותקיו נשלחה לגריסה עם סגירת ההוצאה לאור, על פי החלטת שר הביטחון אהוד ברק]

Translation:

"The story of Moshe Dayan", Ministry of Defense - Publishing, 1997. 
([Ehud Ben-Ezer: "Courage: The Story of Moshe Dayan"](http://www.ithl.org.il/page_13757))
[A rare book that also ran out, the rest of its copies sent to shred when the publishing house closed, according to Defense Minister Ehud Barak's decision]

(the grammatical quirks and language are in the original)

Moshe Dayan allegedly said:

> "ככה זה כשנלחמים עם ערבים," משוכנע משה מאז הקרב על הדגניות: "אם נותנים דפיקה אחת בפח – הם כולם בורחים, כמו ציפורים."

Translation:

> "That's the way it is when fighting with Arabs," Moshe is convinced since the battle for the Deganiot, "If you put one knock on the tin bin - they all run away, like birds."

Note that this quote is from 1948 when Dayan was still a battalion commander, and is not necessarily racist but reflects the kind of fighting that took place against non organised mobs or poorly trained armies.

I couldn't find *this* quote anywhere else using different wording. The exact quote inquired in the question is even more elusive.

Comment: That's a start. But could you give fuller details on the reference & perhaps contrast that more with other sources, like [כרך ראשון: ארבעים ושמונה שנה 1925–1973
עם המהדורה החדשה](https://benyehuda.org/read/14704/read)?

Comment: Actually like I have said I couldn't figure out what this web site is about, and I couldn't find an online copy of the book except for other general references to it.
The reference you brought mentions Dayan but nothing of the kind the question is about, so is this [PDF](https://www.idf.il/media/47115/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F.pdf)

Comment: According to https://library.osu.edu/projects/hebrew-lexicon/ the site is at least Ohio State University and this project a hodgepodge collection (maybe just the organisation of it or the layout confuses me?) of Hebrew 'literature', in this case a 2011 news letter supposedly quoting that book http://www.ithl.org.il/page_13757?

Comment: which among other things archives "חדשות בן עזר" [https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8](Ben Ezer News) where the quote comes from, but this is not too relevant to our discussion here except for the question to the accuracy of the quote

Comment: Hm, books is indeed hard to come by. But according to this https://books.google.com/books?id=MOyVBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT77&lpg=PT77 the expression is even further away from Dayan…, but  https://books.google.com/books?id=Fi8qtb7qcEMC&pg=PT160